# Xcode 9 Server unknown team

Tags: xcode, certificate, xcode9, xcode-server, xcode-bots

The list of certificates in the Xcode Bot Signing tab give me two "Unknown team" entries. The Developer Certificate actually matches the Developer Certificate of Team A (Yellow), while the Distribution Certificate matches Team B (Green). I'm really confused here. Someone knowns what this is and knows how to clean this up?

[image]

Comment: In Keychain Access, do you have any duplicate/conflicting/expired certificates showing? Perhaps even a hidden conflict between login keychain and System keychain? Asking for a friend...

Comment: @christopherdrum Can’t tell you. We have switched to Jenkins + Fastlane recently. Especially fastlane’s match to handle all the certificates and provisioning profiles.

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/110438 > Experienced same issue, Apps validate and distribute fine, so I guess this is just a display issue introduced by XCode 10.1